# How to iterate through Pandas and return first match found in sublist

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, apply

I need a pandas apply function to iterate through sublists and return the first value found for each sublist.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'project_names': [['Datalabor', 'test', 'tpuframework'], ['regETU', 'register', 'tpuframework'], [], ['gpuframework', 'cpuframework']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

I have an nested project list with sublists like this:

```
project_list_1 = [
    ['labor', 'DataLab', 'Anotherdatalabor'],
    ['reg', 'register'],
    ['gpu'],
    ['tpu']
]

project_list_1
```

The final output should look like this:

```
data = {'matches': [['labor', 'tpu'], ['reg', 'tpu'], [None], ['gpu']]}
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

final_df
```

I tried something like this:

```
df2['matches'] = df['project_names'].apply(lambda row: next((project for project in project_list_2 if any(project.lower() in word.lower() for word in row)), None))
df2
```

The method works only for flat lists like this. To collect the first elements found I am using `next()` instead of a list comprehension.

```
project_list_2 = ['labor', 'DataLab', 'register', 'gpu', 'reg', 'tpu']
```

I need to run the method on project_list_1 and get the desired output described above.

Comment: just replace you empty sublist with none. That should work.

Comment: None values can occur. They are fine. The challenge is to evolve the apply method which is working for flat lists to work with nested lists.

Comment: why don't you then flatten the list at first? Like this 

```# Flatten the project_list_1 to enable a similar comparison as with project_list_2
flat_project_list_1 = [item for sublist in project_list_1 for item in sublist]```

And then you can run similar command with the apply method

Comment: If I flat the list, I loose the sublist structure. Each sublist identifies a project name and all of its different ways to spell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
project_list_1 = [
    ["labor", "DataLab", "Anotherdatalabor"],
    ["reg", "register"],
    ["gpu"],
    ["tpu"],
]


def fn(v, project_list):
    out = []
    for project in project_list:
        for p in map(str.lower, project):
            if any(w for w in map(str.lower, v) if (rv := p) in w):
                out.append(rv)
                break
    return out or [None]


df["matches"] = df["project_names"].apply(fn, project_list=project_list_1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                      project_names       matches
0   [Datalabor, test, tpuframework]  [labor, tpu]
1  [regETU, register, tpuframework]    [reg, tpu]
2                                []        [None]
3      [gpuframework, cpuframework]         [gpu]
```

Comment: Where should I implement the lower() method like in my example so that case sensitivity doesn't matter?

Comment: @Daniel I've updated my answer.

Comment: It actually works, but would it be too cumbersome to translate this into a one-liner like my example? Performance is an issue with my real-world dataset, which is much larger. Otherwise, I would likely accept the solution as it is.

Comment: @Daniel One-liner in this case won't provide any benefits (regarding speed). It will be only hard to read. If you want to speed-up the code, convert the strings in `project_names` and `project_list_1` to lowercase before `.apply()` (to not have these `map()` inside the function).

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error. This seems to be fixed if you do the following even with an empty list.

```
# Create df2 as a new DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

# Now you can add the 'matches' column to df2
df2['matches'] = df['project_names'].apply(
    lambda row: next(
        (sublist[0] for sublist in project_list_1 if any(proj.lower() in word.lower() for word in row for proj in sublist if proj and word)),
        None
    )
)
df2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But the task is not to fix the error.